# Cant install deep nested node js modules

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, visual-studio-2015, ntvs

I'm trying to install nightmare module to my project but i'm facing some problems.
When i run `npm install nightmare --save` it all works , and npm returns OK but visual studios says that i reached the max character limit , because of nightmare deeply nested dependencies.The project is already in the shortest path , but the modules still go over the character limit.

Im running windows 10 x64 bit , node v 4.1.0 , npm 2.14.3, visual studios 2015 community with NTVS 1.0 .

I know its a common bug and i searched the web for it , but couldn't find a proper solution.Help is much appreciated

Cheers!

Comment: "but visual studios says that i reached the max character limit"  What's the specific error?

Comment: Try moving the app to a shorter path. e.g. c:\App\. On windows I've had troubles with long paths. Somehow there is a limit to the length of the path + filenames. Another trick is to put it on the network and map network drive to the full path

Comment: I'm not a home , but it says something like this : your path eceded the 260 charchers limit. Vusual studios does  not fully support these projects. And there there is there options to run defub , do nothing and worn me next time or to ignore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i installed the latest npm and it fixed it for me. The npm 3 will install all modules in the parent folder , but remembers the 'tree'.

Answer (score 0):

Use Windows `subst` command to create a virtual drive letter for your source code folder containing the nested `node_modules` folders:

`subst s: c:\path\to\my\long\folder\structure\code\`

Then try to open your project in Visual Studio from drive `s:\`

Comment: I don't think my my path to the project is causing the programs because its located under D:/project/theProjectImworkingOn

Comment: Look inside `the node_modules` folder which will contain another `node_modules` folder and so on... and count your path length.